# Telling ocamlbuild to use Core

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

In my project I have a file that uses Core.Std stuff, so I have run

```
opam install core
```

and added

```
open Core.Std
```

in my file.

When I run

```
ocamlbuild myprogram.native
```

it says:

```
Error: Unbound module Core
```

pointing to line with the open statement above.

So, I try this:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkgs core.std myprogram.native
```

and get the following message:

```
ocamlfind: Package `core.std' not found
```

So I thought that maybe I needed to run opam install core.std as well, but apparently there is no such thing according to opam. I also tried "open Core.Std;;" in the ocaml repl, but that did not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: You really should mark the one answer that helped you as correct, as a reward to your answerer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either use `corebuild` which is usually  shipped with this library or, you can try this:

```
 ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg core
```

P.S. use `ocamlfind list` command to view the list of available packages.

P.P.S. In addition to `corebuild` they usually ship `coretop`, a script that allows you to run core-enabled top-level. It uses `utop` underneath the hood, so make sure that you have installed it with `opam install utop` (if you're using `opam`), before your experiments.

Comment: How do you supply this flag from myocamlbuild.ml?

Comment: "this" is which one? `-use-ocamlfind` or `-pkg core`?

Comment: The latter; `-pkg core`.

Comment: usually they add this to `_tags` file, and `myocamlbuild.ml` is used to determine a correct set of flags based on `_tags`. Depending on your `myocamlbuld.ml`, you need to add `<**/*> : pkg_core` or `<**/*>: package(core)`. Writing your own `myocamlbuild` plugin is an advanced magic, that usually is not required. Even manually filling `_tags` file is quite unusual. So, maybe you're looking in a wrong direction.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

Remove **.std** from your ocamlbuild cmd?

Comment: Thanks! Now I get a different error message: "ocamlfind: Error from package `threads': Missing -thread or -vmthread switch
Command exited with code 2." and -thread or -vmthread are not switches ocamlbuild accepts.

Comment: vmthread and thread are tags. You also want, `-tag[s] thread`